# Undefined behavior when trying to get the size of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, undefined-behavior

So I am trying to get the value of an array and I managed to find a way to do so. When I use that code by itself, it works well, but when I try to integrate it into a function or macro the value overflows and I get something like 4561033 or something along those lines.

This my current code:

```
__inline int sizeOfArray(BYTE lpArray[]) {
    if(lpArray)
        return (*(&lpArray + 1) - lpArray);

    return 0;
}
```

I figured this is what is called 'undefined behavior', but I am not that knowledgeable in what that means and how to fix it. Any ideas would be well received.

Comment: You can't get the size of an array passed as a function parameter. Full stop.

Comment: How do you think your code gets the size of a array?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yea I realize now what I'm doing, I'm only going deeper in the pointer rabbithole

Comment: You can't pass arrays as function parameters, @NeilButterworth. The above code just uses a misleading syntax to pass a pointer. You could pass a reference to an array though and get the size of that array, but that's then part of the static type. Oh, btw, I wonder why nobody mentioned the use of `std::vector` yet.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt So I could pass an address to the array and use that with the code altered a bit? Also, I want to use normal arrays since this is for a project where I'd like to keep it simple so everyone can use it

Comment: The answer below actually shows the syntax for passing a reference to an array as parameter. If you only have a pointer to the first element, which is fundamentally different, you can't pass that to a function expecting an array though. In other words: It won't work. Use `std::vector` instead!

Comment: Thanks guys, I am aware of the containers, but I really need to keep it stupid simple here ;) EDIT: BYTE is unsigned __int8

Comment: There's a few ways to handle this. Some more effective than others.. Depends on the use case though. Vector is one method, your own wrapped data, a string with a size delimiter as the first byte*, or if memory isn't a concern promotion to an short and using a value above 255 to denote end

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do it like this. That function has no knowledge of the array's length, and no way to find it.

That arithmetic just doesn't work. For one thing, `lpArray` is actually a `BYTE*`.

To find the size of an array:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t sizeOfArray(const T (&)[N])
{
   return N;
}
```

Then:

```
BYTE array[42];
std::cout << sizeOfArray(array) << '\n';  // Output: 42
```

If you attempt to pass the function a pointer, the program will not compile.

So, if instead of an array, you have a dynamically-allocated block of memory behind a pointer:

```
BYTE* ptr = new BYTE[42];
```

… first of all, why? Secondly, in this case you will have to keep track of that size yourself. You could store it into a variable.

Comment: I also tried using this before but I don't think I know how since it says I cannot pass a BYTE* as an argument for some reason

Comment: @Itsenough1 Arrays readily decay to pointers, but it's a mistake to think of pointers and arrays as the same thing or the same type. Once an array has decayed to a pointer, it's not possible to directly recover it's size using that pointer.

Comment: Isn't an array a pointer to its elements? And my parameter is a BYTE[14]

Comment: @Itsenough1 An array is an array. A pointer to the first element of an array is often used to refer to arrays, but they aren't the same thing.

Comment: @Itsenough1: _"Isn't an array a pointer to its elements?"_ No.

Comment: @Itsenough1: _"And my parameter is a BYTE[14]"_ That cannot be true, given the compiler error message you said to us.

Comment: Found the error. It was a BYTE* but I was passing it from my class constructor so I forgot about and didn't see it

Comment: @Itsenough1: Good!

Comment: That's why all "does not work!" questions require an MCVE to be on topic. It weeds out stupid mistakes that can easily be found with some basic research.